# Calling AppActivate on a word 2007 window in Windows 7 gives it focus but doesn't bring it to top of stack

Tags: vba, ms-word, javascript, hta

I'm trying to manipulate Word from an HTA file application. Currently, when I open word, it opens underneath my application. I'd like to open it on top. I've tried using the following JScript to give Word the focus:

```
wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wshShell.AppActivate(doc.windows.Item(1).caption);
```

This works, and word gets focus, but on Windows 7 it stays underneath my app. Is there something else I need to do to bring word to the top?

Comment: I tested this, and AppActivate does bring a window to the front (tested on Windows 7).  However, it will not restore a minimized window.

Comment: Maybe there is a setting somewhere that allows windows to be active but not on the top. I've tried calling the above after a 2.5 second delay, and it's clear when word gets the focus, but it doesn't come to the top. I'll see if I can try it on some more computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't force that window to the front, send your own window to the back!

Try this:

```
<script>
window.blur();
</script>
```

That should send your current window to the background.